# Postgresql: "Offset" Interval from HH:MM:SS to 00:HH:MM

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, time-format

I have a table where exists an interval type column `Duration`. Currently the values are expressed as `HH:MM:SS` with data like:

```
15:32:00
17:01:00
16:02:00
...
```

The problem is that in reality the data resembles only minutes and seconds and the column's values should be updated so that values will become:

```
15:32:00 -> 00:15:32
17:01:00 -> 00:17:01
16:02:00 -> 00:16:02

...
```

What kind of query should be run against the column?

Comment: what is the datatype of the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM duration) * INTERVAL '1' minute + EXTRACT(minute FROM duration) * INTERVAL '1' second
FROM tbl
;
```

---

### **EDIT**

This was my original answer, which does not answer the original question:

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT duration - EXTRACT(hour FROM duration) * INTERVAL '1' hour
FROM tbl
;
```

Which extracts the hour part from the interval and subtracts that from the original value.  Rewrite as `UPDATE` if you really need to update your data.

Comment: You can write that interval construction as `extract(hour from duration) * INTERVAL '1' hour)` for better readability, btw.

Comment: This strips just the hours away. What needs to be achieved is that original hours become new minutes and original minutes become new seconds. But this led answer gave me a good clue on how to approach the problem and I'll post it as an answer to myself.